# Retrieve column name of column having non empty values in a particular row

Tags: mysql

[table showing entries in various columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Lsa.png)

i want column names of the columns which contain not-null value in the given row identified by its url eg:- www.facebook.com.
The output of the query should be
**email,password**

Comment: can you elaborate with some more detail, i mean what actually you want.

Comment: i am getting the current url from the browser using extension and using this url i want to populate current site login form for that i need input field name or id values which are stored in the table shown above like **facebook** has <input type="text" name="email"> so this name-**email** i want to grab from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
select  url, group_concat(null_col separator ',')
from    (
            select  url, 'username' null_col from yourTable where username is null union all
            select  url, 'phone' from yourTable where phone is null union all
            select  url, 'email' from yourTable where email is null union all
            select  url, 'password' from yourTable where password is null union all
            select  url, 'login' from yourTable where login is null
        ) t1
group by url
```

Notice that storing many values in the same column is a famously bad idea, because it makes a hell of a nightmare joining, filtering or doing anything else on that column.

If that concatenation is the end result you need though, the above query should do the trick.

Comment: could you please explain something about null_col seperator you passed as an argument to group_concat and null_col used after 'username'.

Comment: `null_col` is the alias for the second column of the inner query, so it is also the column you want to concatenate. `separator ',' ` means that each value of `null_col` will be separated from the next one by a comma